# Executing the Mouse_Click event twice consecutively in the custom control does not take effect for the second time

Tags: c#, winforms

I add the OnMouseClick in a round button that fully custominzed.When I Click twice quickly, the second click event doesn't work. I think it maybe some problems in winform message dealings. Here is my code :

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseClick(e);
    Point pt = e.Location;
    if (region.IsVisible(pt))
    {
        IsCheck = !IsCheck;
        if (IsCheck)
            ActivateChecked();//change the control color to red
        else
            ActivateCancel();//change the control color to green
    }
}
```

Please help.

I tried double buffer and region.Visible, put the stopwatch to calculate the run time. But I'm it's not this problem. But the winform native button can change color for every click.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmousedoubleclick

Comment: emmm, maybe u misunderstand my meaning, I made two controls,one inherit 'Control' class called A, the other inherit 'Button' class  called B, I found when I click the B, it respond for every click ,but I click A, it alwasy several times not respond in all the click behavior

Comment: When you click twice quickly then the 2nd click generates the MouseDoubleClick event.  Which is why your OnMouseClick method doesn't run.  If you want to turn that off, it isn't very useful for a button-style control for example, then copy paste this into the constructor of your control class: `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false);`

Comment: thanks, it has been solved ,thats really helpful